# Rack-superfeedr: Authenticating web-hook calls from hub

Tags: ruby, rack, superfeedr

This question refers to Superfeedr's official [rack-superfeedr](https://github.com/superfeedr/rack-superfeedr) library. As SuperFeedr supports PubSubHubbub's challenge-response protocol, I'm wondering if the rack-superfeedr library provides this automatically.

Looking at the code, I see subscribe() has a block argument which might be necessary for verification purposes, but I'm not fully clear if that's the case and if so, what should the block contain? Could it be a "secret" constant?

Comment: not clear your last line... more explanation need for that line.